# iOS: Change design at runtime

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am currently doing a mobile shop project. My customer ordered that the new version should be able to switch between two shops where the only difference between the two are that the first one is grey styled and the second one is black styled.

Because the two shops are so similar I don't want to do a source code copy (this would be the easy solution) but not a very flexible one. I am familiar with different design patterns but can't find one that is suitable for my specific problem.

In the application there is a pulldown menu where the two shops can be selected. My view controllers are created programmatically and creates a custom view at viewcontroller did load. The view controllers contain uielements such as uiimage uilabel, uitableview etc. When a new shop is selected all the colors and images should be replaced, but my problem is that I only keep the reference to those elements that I need later on (such as the tableview etc.).

So my question is: what would be the correct solution to solve my problem? Is it possible to use specific design pattern (such as the Strategy pattern) to do this or do I have to make a parameterized solution (or a third)?

Any help would be very a appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards 
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

While you can make use of macros to distinguish between brands. For instance say if you have two brands, say MCDonald and KFC, you can define respective macros in your app and based on the macro following styles will be applied to specified components. The downside of this approach is you end up implementing lot of conditional blocks for supporting different brands.

Or you can create different targets for brands and copy required images to respective targets. But remember to name the images similar across both targets and the application will pick up the required images from selected target. With this approach, you will share the same code base but different resources.

Hope it may give you some idea!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) for customizing colors, and have different images for each target (each target would be a shop version).